# How is the log likelihood calculated for bayesian networks?

Tags: likelihood, causality, bayesian-network, bnlearn

In structure learning, there are score-based methods which rely on information criteria such as BIC or AIC.

BIC, specifically, is defined as:

$$
BIC = k \ln(n) - 2\ln\left(\hat{L}\right)
$$

Where $k$ is the number of parameters in the model, $n$ is the number of training examples and $\hat{L}$ is the likelihood function associating the model itself with observed data $x.$

In the case of structure learning, we are trying to determine how well a bayesian network approximates the underlying causal structure in the observed data. The `bnlearn` R package implements such calculations in its methods and, as far as I can tell, the log-likelihood is usually the preferred likelihood function, as it is supposed to be easier to compute.

So my main question here is: how is $\hat{L}$ calculated in the context of bayesian networks? I understand the "concept" (I think), but I can't seem to visualize a practical way of implementing that. What would be the most straight-forward way of representing such calculation?

Comment: Gaussian net bnlearn log-lik calculation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878957/how-bnlearn-calculates-bic-of-continuous-data/54942496#54942496

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, one could use the "standard" way of calculating likelihood, see [How to calculate the likelihood function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132877/how-to-calculate-the-likelihood-function) in conjunction with `the rule of product decomposition` i.e., [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)) for the network. So the joint-probability for the entire network reads $$P(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}) = {\Large \Pi} P(x_{i}|x_{parent})$$

$x_{parent}$ is the parent of $x_{i}$. One would need to incorporate  this in formulating "standard" likelihood $L(\theta|x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})$, $\theta$ being the parameters.

Comment: I understand the concept. But how do you calculate a given $P(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}) = {\Large \Pi} P(x_{i}|x_{parent})$?

Comment: Construct contingency tables (Conditional probability table) for each node. See [wikipedia  sprinkler example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#Example).  However, please note that to compute $L$ we would need to do maximum likelihood estimation and  it is involved.  Daphne Koller's lecture on MLE on graphical models might give better idea, [here](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/probabilistic-graphical-models-3-learning/maximum-likelihood-estimation-KzlS4).

Answer (score 1):

These slides introduce many popular scoring methods for BNs: [http://www.lx.it.pt/~asmc/pub/talks/09-TA/ta_pres.pdf](http://www.lx.it.pt/%7Easmc/pub/talks/09-TA/ta_pres.pdf)

As I understand, for categorical variables and dataset $D$,

$\text{Likelihood}(D) = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^{q_i} \prod_{k=1}^{r_i} \left( \frac{N_{ijk}}{N_{ij}} \right)^{N_{ijk}}$,

where $n$ is number of variables, $q_i$ is the number of configurations of the parents of the $i$th variable, $r_i$ is number of categories for $i$th variable. $N_{ijk}$ is the number of instances in the dataset $D$, where the $i$th variable takes on the $k$th value while the parents are set in their $j$th configuration. And $N_{ij}$ marginalise out over $k$, so it's the total number of total instances with the $j$th configuration.

My interpretation of this is, denoting $x_i$ the $i$th variable.

$ = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^{q_i} \prod_{k=1}^{r_i} Pr(x_i = k | \text{parents of } x_i \text{ have } j\text{th configuration})^{\text{number of times occurs}}$ .